# How accept both long and double in Spring @ConfigurationProperties annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Here is my `yaml` file:

```yaml
collie:
    crontask:
        command: echo ok
        intervalInMinute: 0.5
```

Here is the code:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "collie.crontask")
@Data
public class CronTaskConfig {

    private String command;

    private Long intervalInMinute;

    public void setIntervalInMinute(String intervalInMinute) {
        this.intervalInMinute = Long.parseLong(intervalInMinute);
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'collie.crontask' to com.xx.union.collie.worker.config.CronTaskConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4948fd7:

    Property: collie.crontask.intervalinminute
    Value: 0.5
    Origin: class path resource [application.yaml]:45:23
    Reason: For input string: "0.5"

Action:

Update your application's configuration`
and :
 org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'cronTaskConfig': Could not bind properties to 'CronTaskConfig'
```

But when I set `intervalInMinute: 1`, it works.

It looks like the problem is the type of value.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you are missing "collie" prefix in your yaml example btw, and try to quote the values: `intervalInMinute: "0.5"`

Comment: yes,hh,i just fix it . But i still get this error when i  quote the values.  Reason: For input string: "0.5"

Comment: `0.5` != Long, is it?

Answer (score 0):

`0.5` is not a `Long`, and can't be converted. Changing to a `double` should work.

Comment: but, Isn't the value injected through the setter method? I do the conversion in the setter method

Comment: and my purpose is to make it accept both long and double

Comment: @dreamck then change `Long intervalInMinute` to `String intervalInMinute` and let the callers to do the conversion as needed

Answer (score 0):

The value `0.5` is an invalid long value. You could parse the double value first:

```java
public void setIntervalInMinute(String intervalInMinute) {
    this.intervalInMinute = (long) Double.parseDouble(intervalInMinute);
}
```